# why comment 2 is not getting sent to data browser

Tags: android, parse-platform

i have the following code

```
public class Destination extends Activity {

EditText destinationPoint;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_destination);
    destinationPoint=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dest);
    Parse.initialize(this, "cccc", "xxxx");
    ParseObject ob=new ParseObject("vamsi"); //1
    ob.put("vamsi"," pavan"); //1
    ob.saveInBackground(); //1


}

public void ridenow(View view){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences("AutoRaja",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sharedPreferences.edit();
    edit.putString("destination", destinationPoint.getText().toString());
    edit.commit();
    String name=sharedPreferences.getString("customerName", "mr x");
    Log.d("name",name);

    String phoneNumber=sharedPreferences.getString("customerNumber", "0000000000");
    Log.d("phone",phoneNumber);
    String pickup=sharedPreferences.getString("pick", null);
    Log.d("pickup",pickup);

    String destination=sharedPreferences.getString("destination", null);
    Log.d("destination",destination);
    ParseObject customerDetails = new ParseObject("Customer"); //2
    customerDetails.put("Name", name);                                 //2
    customerDetails.put("Phone Number",phoneNumber);                    //2 
    customerDetails.put("Pick Up Location", pickup);                    //2
    customerDetails.put("Destination",destination );                     //2
    customerDetails.saveInBackground();                                  //2

    ParseObject ob=new ParseObject("gates");  //3
    ob.put("mill"," billionire");      //3
    ob.saveInBackground();             //3


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.destination, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

So in the above code , i was able to send the //1 and //3 objects to the data browser in parse.com ,but which are useless for me .I need to send //2 customer object ,but it will not go .can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you shouldn't put values in column which name contains spaces, so like Phone Number, Pick Up Location. Try to put an underscore instead ( cloud code side ) so try to put the values in that field (`Phone_Number`, `Pick_Up_Location`)

Comment: yes ,this is one of the point ... but the problem was i did not add the key properly .. +1 anyways